# How to format x labels for a datetime scale

Tags: anychart

I have this chart https://playground.anychart.com/D7okDBpO/4

AFAIK the x labels are automatically formatted according to the `anychart.format.outputDateFormat()`, so the only way to format them is to call `anychart.format.outputDateFormat("someformat")`. The problem is that I have multiple charts on a page and they all need different formats, and changing this global setting from multiple charts leads to concurrency issues (on some charts, the x labels are formatted with multiple different formats).

Is there some other way to format them? Having access to the original data from the formatting function for x labels would be enough, but it's not there:

```
chart.xAxis().labels().format(function () {
    console.log(this); // only contains the already formatted date
    return this.value;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this.tickValue contains unformatted dates, so you can use the {%tickValue} and {%x} string tokens to format the axes labels and the tooltip respectively. Please check this [sample](https://playground.anychart.com/RVi8h4SL), pay attention to lines 35-36.